# input and button, same css, different heights

Tags: html, css

I am having same css properties, yet the button and input fields are different fields

```css
.input-con {
  position: relative;
}

.input-con>* {
  line-height: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: #444;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-con">
  <input type="text" />
  <button>Search</button>
</div>
```

pen - https://codepen.io/digitalzoomstudio/pen/LOoVYK

How could I achieve same heights without forcing *height* property ?

Comment: Simply remove the line-height

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are seeing a discrepancy in the height is due - I think - to the `font` property, which includes shorthand for `font-weight`, `font-size` and `font-family`.

If you explicitly override this property for both `input` and `button` the height will match up.

```css
.input-con {
  position: relative;
}

.input-con>* {
  line-height: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: #444;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input,
button {
  font: 400 15px Arial !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-con">
  <input type="text" />
  <button>Search</button>
</div>
```

**updated as per comment**

It will not work to declare `font-weight`, `font-size` and `font-family` separately, as this does not override the `font` shorthand completely.

The full shorthand is:

```
font: font-style font-variant font-weight font-size/line-height font-family;
```

Only if *each* of these properties is declared will the `font` property be overridden.

- Note that `font` contains three separate properties for `font-variant` (ligatures, caps and numeric) - it seems that using `font-variant` is sufficient.

**demo**

```css
.input-con {
  position: relative;
}

.input-con>* {

  /* override all properties of the 'font' shorthand */
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: normal;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: #444;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-con">
  <input type="text" />
  <button>Search</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you

Best answer because it highlighted the issue, it did not offer work arounds like the others

The font property did the trick 

But just don't understand why setting the properties separate - https://codepen.io/digitalzoomstudio/pen/LOoVYK - would not work the same. Css is weird sometimes.

Comment: @digitalzoomstudio Good observation! I did a bit of investigating and updated the answer -- hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

You can use flex box , just add `display:flex;` on the parent (**input-con**)

```css
.input-con {
  position: relative;
  display:flex;
}

.input-con>* {
  line-height: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: #444;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-right:2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-con">
  <input type="text" />
  <button>Search</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You added `line-height: 1;` which makes difference

```css
.input-con {
  position: relative;
}

.input-con>* {
  /*line-height: 1;*/
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: #444;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-con">
  <input type="text" />
  <button>Search</button>
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: I'm all for the solutions that don't just advise to "use flex" when `flex-box` is not necessary.

Comment: I understand there are solution - like converting line height from em in pixels / removing line height / adding display flex when not necessary ( it will wrap just in one line with flex ) , etc but just don't understand why 1em in line-height would render different heights

Answer (score 0):

Try with this it may help

```
.input-con {
    position: relative;

    }
.input-con{
  position:relative;

  >*{
    vertical-align:middle;  
    padding: 10px; 
    border:0;
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: #444;
    outline:0;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size: 15px;  

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add display:flex like this

```
    .input-con {
    position: relative;
    display:flex;
    }
```

Learn more about [flex](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed Flexbox is the way to go, but if you're curious as why you're getting this behavior CSS Tricks has a good article https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: I understand there are solution - like converting line height from em in pixels / removing line height / adding display flex when not necessary ( it will wrap just in one line with flex ) , etc but just don't understand why 1em in line-height would render different heights